# Problem dropping a sortable on the border

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm trying to sort div elements horizontally using Jquery-ui-sortable. Everything is okay, but when I want to drop a sortable from the right or left, it reverts back to its original position unless it touches the other sortable element on the edge of the list. Is there a way to make it enough for the sortable to touch the paddings of the parent div?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#mainDiv").sortable({
    revert: true,
    tolerance: "pointer",
  }).disableSelection();
});
```

```css
 .wp
 {
   display:inline-block;
   font-size:24pt;
   color:rgb(40,10,180);
   cursor:pointer;
   line-height:40pt;
   vertical-align:middle;
   padding-right:4px;
   padding-left:4px;
   margin-right:4px;
   margin-left:4px;
   border-radius:14px;
   background-color:rgb(240,240,240);
 }
  #mainDiv
 {
   background-color:rgb(245,245,245);
   border: 1px solid grey;
   border-radius:12px;
   padding:14pt;
   display:inline-block;
 }
```

```html
<script name="jquery_script" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script name="jqueryui_script" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="Txt" class="Txt" style="font-size:14pt; margin-top:3%; margin-bottom:1%;">
        <div id="mainDiv" style="margin-top:42px; margin-bottom:24px;">
        <div class="wp" style="opacity: 1;">div1</div>
        <div class="wp" style="opacity: 1;">div2</div>
        <div class="wp">div3</div>
        </div>
</div>
```

I've searched the documentation as well as Stackoverflow but found no solution.

Here is a JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/cccc0000aaaa/rbktm8eo/5/

**A video clip showing the problem**
https://youtu.be/IJ1PEcncaZk

Comment: Checked your fiddle and it seems working fine.

Comment: @RohitMittal
Maybe you didn't get my problem. The problem is, when I hold a sortable and try to drop it on the right/left without dragging it through middle element, it does not get dropped except if I touch the side elements.

Comment: @RohitMittal, here is the issue: https://youtu.be/IJ1PEcncaZk

Comment: try using `tolerance: intersect`

Comment: @Souleste Tried that. Didn't work.